# D Array Key Type

Tags: arrays, types, d

When working with static arrays, what's type of the key of the array? I am sure I've seen it being mentioned before but I can't find it again.

Also the documentation says the size of a static array cannot exceed 16MB. Does this mean that when creating a *byte* array, the array can be bigger, as in have more different key-value pairs, than when using say *long*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the key type of `byte[1024]` is `size_t` just like it is for dynamic arrays

`size_t` is an alias of an integral type specifically for indices